# Why are these sequences reversed when generated with the colon operator?

Tags: r

I've noticed that when I try to generate a list of sequences with the `:` operator (without an anonymous function), the sequences are always reversed.  Take the following example.

```
x <- c(4, 6, 3)
lapply(x, ":", from = 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 3 2 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 6 5 4 3 2 1
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 2 1
```

But when I use `seq`, everything is fine.

```
lapply(x, seq, from = 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

And from `help(":")` it is stated that

> For other arguments `from:to` is equivalent to `seq(from, to)`, and generates a sequence from `from` to `to` in steps of 1 or -1.

**Why is the first list of sequences reversed?**

Can I generated forward sequences this way with the colon operator with `lapply`?
Or do I always have to use `lapply(x, function(y) 1:y)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ":" operator is implemented as the primitive [do_colon](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/86b832f58109a3c71f321e8eb080323e8aebd389/src/main/seq.c#L145) function in C. This primitive function does not have named arguments. It simply takes the first parameter as the "from" and the second as the "to" ignorning any parameter names. See

```
`:`(to=10, from=5)
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5
```

Additionally the `lapply` function only passes it's values as a leading unnamed parameter in the function call. You cannot pass values to primitive functions via `lapply` as the second positional argument.

Comment: Ah, so the "arguments" in the help file are not actual arguments

Comment: They are just not named augments. The names are only there to help you understand the syntax in the help function. They could have called the "a" and "b" or something. It would have been difficult to describe without a placeholder name at all.

Comment: The key here is the word "primitive" which also applies to the "["-function. The `i` and `j` arguments to "[" cannot be supplied by name, only position.

Comment: I do not think the last sentence in the answer is correct. It's easy to see a counter-example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895769/programming-with-dplyr-0-3/26896696#26896696 . It would be more accurate to say that `lapply` supplies its arguments to the first argument in the formals list that is not also supplied via names to the ellipsis in the `lapply` call.

Comment: You can pass values as the second positional argument if you "fill-up" the first position with a named argument via the ellipsis

Comment: @BondedDust If you look at `foo<-function(x, ...) {print(sys.call()); print(match.call()); invisible(NULL)}; lapply(4, foo, x=3)`, i guess i'm referring to the behavior of `sys.call()` where it is passed as the first param, but logically it can behave like a second parameter as seen in `match.call()`. We've just seen that with a primitive, there would be no way to fill up that first parameter so i prefer the model where its always passed as the first because i think that makes it easier to predict behavior.

Comment: Might be worth adding that `mapply(":", 1L, x)` gets the job done nicely